# Newton's Method, Analytical Formula

Tags: numerical-methods

Currently I am learning about Netwon's Method. Given the function f: $\frac{1}{5} x^5 - \frac{2}{3}x^3 + x$ and $x^{(0)} = \sqrt{\frac{  25+2\sqrt{55} }{27} }$, I want to analytically determine the sequence $x^{(n+1)} = \Psi(x^{(n)})$ with
$\Psi(x) := x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. Can someone show me how this is done in this particular case?

Comment: Interessting starting point, why did you choose that one ?

Comment: butterfly effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the sequence, given by a recursion. For arbitrary sequence it is not possible to find any formula (even not a recursive one).

As this is a numerical method, why do you want to do it analytical? If you want the analytical solutions use 
$$\frac{1}{5} x^5 - \frac{2}{3} x^3 + x= x( \frac{1}{5} x^4 - \frac{2}{3} x^2 +1) $$
so $0$ is a solution and the others you get by using pq formal with $z=x^2$

Comment: Thanks. Why is it for arbitrary sequences not possible to find a recursion? Isn't the recursion given by Newton's Method? I.e. can I not construct a recursion via this method?

Comment: Oh i mean with arbitrary sequences really arbitrary sequences. Newton methods always give you the recursion, but there are sequences which don't come from an newton iteration

Comment: In case you are interested, I figured that the function is always oscillating and hence the values are always x_0,-x_0,x_0 etc. I wonder if there was a way to see this just by inspecting the formula?

Comment: the values are something like $0.233$ than $-0.0184$

Comment: ..so I get $\pm 1.2146085632857550969148471364800765701899398426479169$

Comment: oh right, I did made a mistake in the Formala, i guess you only see it, after you calculated it